# Rails 4: dynamically added checkboxes are not submitting

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, activerecord

I started to learn Rails and try to apply AJAX with some records that are added dynamically in a listing. Then I want to delete multiple records that are selected via checkboxes directly in the listing.

**It works fine but not when I create a new Record and want to delete it without refreshing the page**. The header's response is : "ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in AccountsController#destroym". It acts as if I click the button without checking my checkboxes.

Thanks for your help :)

**accounts_controller.rb**

```
def destroym
  Account.destroy(params[:delete])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html {redirect_to accounts_path}
    format.js #render accounts/destroym.js.erb
  end
end
```

**_row.html.erb**

```html
<% @data = Account.find(id) %>
<tr id='tr<%= @data.id %>'> 
<td><%= @data.id %></td> 
<td><%= @data.login %></td>
<td><%= check_box_tag 'delete[]', @data.id  %></td>
</tr>
```

**index.html.erb**

```html
<table class="table table-striped table-hover " id="accountsListing">
              <%= form_tag destroym_accounts_path, method: :DELETE, remote: true, id: "deleteForm" do %>
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <th>Username</th>
                    <th>Password</th>
                    <th>Website</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Editer</th>
                    <th><%= submit_tag "delete" %>
                    <%= link_to "Delete", '', :onclick => "$('#deleteForm').submit()", id: "removePwd", class: "text-danger", remote: true, method: :DELETE %> </th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <% @accounts.each do |account| %>
                  <%= render 'row', id: account.id %>
                <% end %>
                </tbody>
              <% end %>
            </table>
```

**destroym.js.erb**

```
$("#accountsListing input:checked").closest("tr").remove();
```

**create.js.erb**

```
$("#accountsListing tr:first").after("<%= escape_javascript (render 'row', id:@account.id) %>");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in this case is that you're replacing your whole page's HTML... So, all the DOM events bound to your elements are also destroyed.

When you replace your html (the .js.erb file), Rails will provide some special attributes to your elements (Rails calls that ["unobstrusive JavaScript"](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs), because there's no JS code directly in your elements).

The issue here, of course, is that the JS code that Rails uses (see my link) are only applied when the page launches.

You have several choices:

1) your `destroy.js.erb` can only remove the exact row you just deleted (instead of replacing all the rows).

2) you can call rails-ujs' code by yourself. This is a hack and should not seriously be considered.

3) you can reload the page "automatically" (you lose the benefit of AJaX).

4) you can write your own JS code to send the AJaX request.

Comment: Thanks Ven. Regarding the 1) , I prefer that solution. I have replaced destroym.js.erb with `$("#accountsListing input:checked").closest("tr").fadeOut('slow');`

But I still can not Delete more than one time.

Thanks

Comment: Actually, now I see an error in the console: `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in AccountsController#destroym

Couldn't find Account with 'id'=100`

100 is the id of the fist account I have deleted. It's like every checkbox I check after is stated with the id of the first delete...

Comment: The problem is that your `fadeOut` will **not** remove the element from the DOM. So, every time you submit again, the other checkboxes are still sent (though they are "invisible").

Comment: you can provide a callback function to `fadeOut`, that'll be called once the element is done fading out. In your case, you'll want to completly remove the element from the DOM (another option is unchecking the box).

Comment: Ven , thanks for your answers. Really helped me going forward and edit the code the right way. Please see my edits in my main post above! I can now destroy multiple rows on the second submit. But there is still an issue when I add dynamically a new record, I can not remove this record just after creating it. It looks like all the checkboxes added dynamically are not recognized by my form submit. If I want to delete the record I have to refresh the page...

Comment: The "add a new row dynamically" exhibits exactly the issue I talk about in my answer. Your options left are the one areforementioned in my post

Comment: I guess my only option is to write my own AJAX request in JS. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My solution to handle checkboxes created dynamically. The **on** function is mandatory if you want to handle events on elements added dynamically.

**JS code**

```
$("#deleteBtn").on("click", function() {

    var ids = [];
    $('#accountsListing :checkbox:checked').each(function(){
        ids.push($(this).val());
     });

    $.ajax({
    url: '/accounts/destroym',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        "_method":"DELETE",
        "authenticity_token": window._token,
        "delete[]": ids
    },
    });
});
```